# Is it possible to enable chatbot/liveagent for internal users?

Tags: liveagent, einstein, bots

I would like to enable chatbot for internal users, but i don't think there is an option out of the box that allow me to do that.

How can I show the chat button in the salesforce org?

Comment: I'm assuming, but are you thinking of the Admins as the "agent" and the other internal users as the "Customers"? I'd be interested in how it could be done and possibly the chat deployment script could be used within a LWC?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to Enable Einstein Bot for internal users. For that you will have to configure a visualforce page and place it in the Utility Bar. For details on how to configure Einstein Bot in a Visualforce page please refer to the following article.
[Einstein Bots for Employees, The Easy Way](https://chatbotslife.com/einstein-bots-for-employees-the-easy-way-4ccf80e4ae16)

Answer (score 0):

There are two routes for this,

1. Enable the Chatbot only for the skill that is only available for the Internal Users. If this sounds good to you, the next question would be how? To achieve this, on your Prechat page (Form Page where you are starting your chat), exempt the Skill that is only available to the Internal Users.
2. If you want to use the same skills for both customers and your internal users, then as of now there is no way to achieve this.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, you can create a skill for only internal users, but it's useless if you can't display the chat button to the internal users within their org. All examples are for communities and external sites with the supplied deployment/button code.

Comment: Well, that is the downfall here.